# rails : grape-swagger-rails API request with http instead of https in swagger documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, grape-api

The API is hosted on https. When I try to request the API, the request is made to http instead of https which gives error result.

```
Mixed Content: The page at .... ....was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
```

How to set it to make request on https instead of http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have not set base_path in base.rb
To solve this problem we need to add

```
add_swagger_documentation base_path: "https://ssl.domain.com"
```